# how to populate in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose

```js
var headSchema = new Schema({
  typename: String,
  headname: String,
  status: { type: Number, default: 1 }
});
var Head = mongoose.model("heads", headSchema);

var mgmtSchema = new Schema({
  headtype: String,
  type: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Head" },
  datefrom: Date,
  dateto: Date,
  title: String,
  amount: Number,
  description: String,
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  status: Number
});

var HeadMgmt = mongoose.model("headmgmt", mgmtSchema);

HeadMgmt.find({})
  .populate({ path: "type", select: "headname" })
  .exec(function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```

I have two schemas, also foreign key reference. The second schema has some value. I need to display the lists in one html table. How can print headname from head schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `mgmtSchema` you need to change the ref value in type field from `Head` to `heads`, because you used `heads`setup your Head model like this:

```js
var Head = mongoose.model("heads", headSchema);
```

So your mgmtSchema must be like this:

```js
var mgmtSchema = new Schema({
  headtype: String,
  type: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "heads" },
  datefrom: Date,
  dateto: Date,
  title: String,
  amount: Number,
  description: String,
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  updated_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  status: Number
});
```

The result of your current populate code will be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5e13483dd62cd92e3c3e8dcd",
        "headtype": "headtype",
        "type": {
            "_id": "5e1347671b0bd339e0521139",
            "headname": "headname 1"
        },
        "title": "title",
        "amount": 123,
        "description": "description",
        "created_at": "2020-01-06T14:46:21.906Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-06T14:46:21.906Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: @athira-appu I appreciate if you can also upvote this answer.